# Devise showing error 'invalid email or password' upon going to login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 3 with Devise and have setup my routes.rb file like so:

```
  devise_for :users,
  :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}

  devise_scope :user do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create'
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  resources :users
```

When I go to /login I get the flash messages:

```
Signed out successfully.
Invalid email or password.
```

The first message is a notice and I'm not worried about it, but the second one is an alert and is annoying as the user hasn't hit sign in yet and it's already complaining that there is no password.

Is there an easy way to suppress this message? Have I setup devise wrong maybe.

I'm using username field to login instead of email.

I have changed my devise.rb to have

```
  config.authentication_keys = [ :username ]
```

Comment: My issue was solved when I restarted the server after running the migrations. For some reason, the server cached something and would not accept the credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an easy mistake when I look back at it with a fresh head:

This

```
get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create'
```

Should be

```
get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#new'
```